# Which users here use the chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

The [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1878/computational-science) has been largely empty for more than a year.

Since December 2019 the room has mainly been used by myself, uhoh, and David Z to post questions from other sites which would be of interest to Computational Scientists or HPC users. Every time I visit the chat though, there's zero people other than me, that have recently been in the chat room. So who actually would see such posts?

If you visit the chat room somewhat regularly (at least once every 2 weeks), perhaps you can comment or answer with some perspective of why you do it (or how often you do it, or why you don't do it, or what you know about the user chat usage here and why no one in this community likes to use chat anymore).

Answer (score 2):

I visit the room occasionally (say, 2 times a week), mostly, as a moderator, to check if there is something that needs my attention. It rarely does.

I see the questions you are posting in the chat room, and some of them I find interesting. So, I would encourage you to continue (if nobody minds), unless you are not fine with having a very small audience.

Unfortunately, this community is not too active in the chat. Seems, like there is a community preference to do a pure Q/A, or a discussion in chat for particular questions, not via a general chat room.

Comment: Thank you for your input Anton :) It's good to see at least one person checks the room and might benefit from the cross-site HPC questions that users like myself and uhoh and David Z are adding. Hopefully more answers will show up, indicating that it's not just you popping occasionally into the chat room!

Comment: I would like to try to follow up on this as I see two of my posts in the chat deleted: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55385302#55385302. Do you happen to know who deleted them? Perhaps they didn't see this meta post saying that we are encouraged to continue contributing questions that might be of interest to compsci? The first one deleted was a clear HPC (high performance computing) question specifically aimed at people doing computational science on ARM machines (just like 10 years ago people would ask about GPUs), the 2nd was about error propagation.

Comment: @user1271772 replied in the chat room. There is no such policy in our community (yet), and your links were useful and appropriate to the chat room. While for some communities, this might not be acceptable, I don't (at least yet) find the amount of questions you promote in our chat excessive.